# My Java application crashes because of this method

Tags: java, android

My application crashes because of this method. Please help :=)

```
public void sortedList() {
    String goodLetter = "B";

    for (String myItem : myArrayList) {
        String myFirstChar = myItem.substring(0, 1);
        if (myFirstChar != goodLetter) {
            myArrayList.remove(myItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The least you could do is provide the stack trace for the crash

Comment: regardless of the error, consider using the equals() method for String comparison, as you want to compare the values of the objects, not the objects themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will crash if:

- myArrayList contains a `null` element (NullPointerException)
- myArrayList contains the empty String (IndexOutOfBoundsException)
- Any element from myArrayList does not start with "B" (ConcurrentModificationException)

For that last, and most probable, cause see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) linked by @Todd in the comments.

Additionally, in Java you should compare Strings using `.equals` instead of `==` or `!=`.

Comment: You could consider immediately switching over to [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/), where once again it is fine to compare Strings using `==` ;)

Comment: Exactly because of the bug in string comparison it will probably crash with a word that does start with `B` too.

Answer (score 0):

First, for string comparison, use `String.equals()` and not `==`.
Second, if you want to remove objects from a list :

- do a reverse browsing
- or create an intermediary array containing objects to remove